# Add an existing shared datasource to bids

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, bids

when using SSRS i'am always using a new datasource,but now I need to use a shared datasource already created.
My problem is that i cannot find my shared datasource in bids and i do not know how to import it.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: You need to create a Shared Data source in bids called the same as the one in production.. Once your report is deployed to prod then it will access that one

Comment: Is there anyrisk ,i overwrite the existingone?thank you

Comment: Are you connectiing directly to Prod in BIDS?

Comment: if i create a new datasource so yes ,i can see my data .but I need to use another ds(which is a shared ds).

Comment: if you have created shared datasource, there will be file created in your project directory with extension .rds.  you can add this existing for new project.  do add existing (or Shift + Alt + A) for share datasource.